# different costraints beetwen ios7 and ios8

Tags: swift, constraints

I have a `UITextview` with trailing, leading, bottom and top space constraints. It layout is perfect in iOs 8 but in iOs 7 is not the same.

iOs 8 screen shot:
[Example](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1372/52Cuc8.png)

iOs 7 screen shot:
[Example](http://imageshack.com/a/img913/9984/aUACm8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not to set constraints to margin. In iOs7 there aren't.